# Consulta de packages en Python

Tags: python, packages

Estoy haciendo mis primeras pruebas para crear packages en python y no estaría lográndolo.

Tengo una carpeta llamada funciones, la que contiene n archivos de código python pero para la consulta va 1:

`folder/func.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def function():
    print("soy una función")
    return
```

`folder/__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from func import function
```

Y por último en el directorio raiz del proyecto...
programa.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import folder
folder.function
```

Yo esperaba que al correr programa.py mostrara en consola "soy una función" pero recibo el siguiente error:

> File "/.../prueba/programa.py", line 3, in  import folder
> File "/.../prueba/folder/**init**.py", line 1, in  from func import function
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func'

Alguna idea de dónde estoy metiendo la pata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo __ init__.py
te falto el punto antes del func
es decir:

```
from .func import function
```

solo eso, el resto esta bien

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Introduje la corrección que me diste y si bien no muestra un mensaje de error al correr el código, tampoco muestra el mensaje "soy una función".

Comment: @k3rn3l00ps recuerda poner los paréntesis al hacer el llamado a la función

Comment: Sos un capo!!! Se me había pasado ese "detallito". Muchísimas gracias thotenn y @Christian por su tiempo y sapiencia!